# How to deal with common arguments for several helper functions in a module?

Tags: performance-tuning, pure-function

Suppose a module exports functions like `Calculate1[...,T]`, and `Calculate2[...,T]` which have several arguments in addition to `T`. They both call lots of helper functions defined in the module, which all depend on `T`. What is the best way to handle this situation?

I could just have an extra slot for each function to specify `T`, but this would get really tedious, especially as there can be more common arguments like `T`:

```
k1 = Function[{..., T, T2, T3}, ...]
k2 = Function[{..., T, T2, T3}, ...]
k3 = Function[{..., T, T2, T3}, ...]
(* etc. *)
Calculate1 = Function[{..., T, T2, T3}, k1[..., T, T2, T3] + k2[..., T, T2, T3] + ...]
Calculate2 = Function[{..., T, T2, T3}, k1[..., T, T2, T3] - k2[..., T, T2, T3] + ...]
```

I could put all of the functions within a giant `With` like this:

```
Calculate1=With[{T=#,T2=#2,T3=#3,...},
  k1=...;
  k2=...;
  k1 + k2 + k3 ...
]
```

I'm not sure if having functions defined within a `With` changes how they get compiled. And I would have to repeat for `Calculate2`.

I could also just have a global symbol within the module as a one time side-effect within the module.

Each of these three approaches I dislike for different reasons. Is there an obvious choice from these, or is there a better way altogether?

Answer (score 1):

since you are not modifying values for `T`,`T2` and `T3` I find no problem in using `With`. You can define `k1`,`k2` and `k3` with a `:=`

```
Calculate = Block[{k1, k2, k3},
With[{T = #, T2 = #2, T3 = #3},
 k1 := T*T2*T3;
 k2 := T*(T2 - T3);
 k3 := T*(T2 + T3);
 k1 + k2 + k3]
] &;

Calculate[a, b, c]
(* a (b - c) + a b c + a (b + c) *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I unfortunately left out that I actually need to export several such functions that make use of the same helpers (see edited question).